# Compare adjacent values in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Numpy one-dimensional array of data, something like this

```
a = [1.9, 2.3, 2.1, 2.5, 2.7, 3.0, 3.3, 3.2, 3.1]
```

I want to create a new array, where the values are composed of the greater of the adjacent values.  For the above example, the output would be:

```
b = [2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 2.7, 3.0, 3.3, 3.3, 3.2]
```

I can do this by looping through the input array, comparing the neighbouring values, eg:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.9, 2.3, 2.1, 2.5, 2.7, 3.0, 3.3, 3.2, 3.1])
b = np.zeros(len(a)-1)

for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if (a[i] > a[i+1]):
        b[i] = a[i]
    else:
        b[i] = a[i+1]
```

but I'd like to do this in a more elegant "pythonic" vectorised fashion.  I've searched and read about np.zip, np.where, np.diff etc but haven't yet found a way to do this (or more likely, I haven't understood what is possible).  Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want element-wise maximum of `a[1:]` and `a[:-1]`:

```
>>> a
array([ 1.9,  2.3,  2.1,  2.5,  2.7,  3. ,  3.3,  3.2,  3.1])
>>> a[1:]
array([ 2.3,  2.1,  2.5,  2.7,  3. ,  3.3,  3.2,  3.1])
>>> a[:-1]
array([ 1.9,  2.3,  2.1,  2.5,  2.7,  3. ,  3.3,  3.2])
>>> np.maximum(a[1:], a[:-1])
array([ 2.3,  2.3,  2.5,  2.7,  3. ,  3.3,  3.3,  3.2])
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks !  That was just what I was looking for.  Simple once you see it :)